# InvalidAuthenticityToken from form in Rails 5.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, refactoring, authenticity-token

I had a working Rails5.2 application that needed a database restructure to improve the organisation of some tables. Since this change, I've found that some of my forms fails consistently on my local machine with this error:

```rb
ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken in PayBandsController#create
```

I've had to change a lot in the application as part of the refactor, of course, but the tests are all passing.

I can avoid the issue by setting `skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token` on the relevant controller (per previous SO threads) but this isn't a good fix, of course. I'd like to know what the root cause is and eliminate it.

- The form works when it's on its own page, placed with `render` in the HTML.
- The form works when I set the `skip_before_action`.
- The form fails with an AuthenticityToken error otherwise - even though the same structure worked before.

This is all tested on my local machine with a valid session.

---

The form is created within a service object as the final line of a data table (so that I can add new lines to the table). Is this a potential cause of the problem - it's rendered in the service object rather than in the ERB? Although this approach worked fine before the refactor...

```rb
_table_data += ApplicationController.render(partial: 'datasets/pay_band_numbers_form', locals:{ _dataset_id: _dataset.id, _namespace: _key })
```

The partial is as follows and, as I said, works if placed on a page by itself (e.g. pay_bands/new) but not where it needs to be (on dataset/edit):

```
<%= form_for (PayBand.new), namespace: _namespace do |f| %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :dataset_id, :value => _dataset_id %>
  <%= f.text_field :label, :tabindex => 11, :required => true %>
  <%= f.number_field :number_women, :tabindex => 12, :required => true %>
  <%= f.number_field :number_men, :tabindex => 13, :required => true %>
  <%= f.submit "&#10004;".html_safe, :tabindex => 14, class: "button green-button checkmark" %>
<% end %>
```

The models involved are Dataset and PayBand, which are defined as follows.

```rb
class Dataset < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :organisation
  has_many :pay_bands, inverse_of: :dataset, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :pay_bands
  default_scope -> { order(created_at: :desc) }
  validates :name, presence: true
  validates :organisation_id, presence: true
end
```

```rb
class PayBand < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :dataset
  has_many :ages_salaries_genders, inverse_of: :pay_band, dependent: :destroy
  validates :dataset_id, presence: true
  validates :label, presence: true
end
```

The relevant parts of the dataset controller are:

```rb
class DatasetsController < ApplicationController
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  load_and_authorize_resource
  before_action :authenticate_user!
.
.
.
  def edit
    @dataset = Dataset.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @dataset = Dataset.find(params[:id])
    if @dataset.update_attributes(dataset_params) && dataset_params[:name]
      flash[:notice] = "Survey updated"
      redirect_back fallback_location: dataset_path(@dataset)
    else
      flash[:alert] = "Attempted update failed"
      redirect_to edit_dataset_path(@dataset)
    end
  end
.
.
.
  private

    def dataset_params
      params.require(:dataset).permit(:name)
    end

end
```

The pay-band controller is:

```rb
class PayBandsController < ApplicationController
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  # skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token #DANGEROUS!!!!!
  load_and_authorize_resource
  before_action :authenticate_user!

  def create
    @pay_band = PayBand.new(pay_band_params)
    if @pay_band.save
      flash[:notice] = "Data saved!"
      redirect_to edit_dataset_path(Dataset.find(@pay_band.dataset_id))
    else
      flash[:alert] = "There was an error. Your data was not saved."
      redirect_back fallback_location: edit_dataset_path(Dataset.find(pay_band_params[:dataset_id]))
    end
  end

  private

    def pay_band_params
      params.require(:pay_band).permit(:label, :number_women, :number_men, :avg_salary_women, :avg_salary_men, :dataset_id)
    end
end
```

All of the above controller structure is identical to the working version of the app, before I fiddled with the data models!

===

**Edit**

I decided to check the headers, after some more research, so see if I could see the token value. However, the token value in the `meta csrf-token` header tag doesn't match any of the 3 different tokens in the 3 different forms on this page. But one works anyway (the simple form that's just `render`ed in the ERB template) and the other two don't (the ones `render`ed in the service object). Which all leaves me just as confused as I was before!

Also, I tried removing Turbolinks from my GemFile and application.js file, re-running `bundle` and `rails s`, but it made no difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future reference for anyone else having the same problem (AuthenticityToken errors for a form that's been built in a helper or service object), I moved the form directly into the view and `render`ed it there - and the problem disappeared. I've removed the `skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token` and all is now well!

Comment: Would be interested in how. Note that I refer in this answer to *restoring* the check that I'd skipped only to test, noted above in my own code in the question as a very dangerous thing to have skipped! The whole point of this question was finding a way to resolve the problem without skipping this check. (I'd appreciate my rep back, too...)